# MySQL get a list of values not in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables. One is called cards

```
Cards
CardNo
----------------
111111
222222
333333
444444
```

and the other table is called customers

```
Customers
ID | CardNo
----------------
1       | 111111
2       | 222222
3       | 444444
```

I am trying to write a query that will return a list of cards not assigned to customers, here is the query I came up with:

```
SELECT * FROM cards WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT CardNo FROM customers WHERE CardNo IS NOT NULL);
```

But nothing gets returned, is my query incorrect or have all cards been assigned to customers?

Thanks,

Comment: You need a correlated subquery when you use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`. You could use `WHERE cardNo NOT IN (SELECT ...)`

Comment: `select * from cards c left join Customers cc on c.CardNo = cc.CardNo where cc.CardNo is null`

Comment: "But nothing gets returned".  Of course nothing is returned.  Look at your inner query.  Will column `CardNo` ever be `NULL` in `Customers` table?  If not, then nothing gets returned is expected.